# How to say 'presenter' in a workshop?

Tags: hispanoamérica

In describing details about a workshop, I'm listing the presenting person/organization, the location, the date, and giving a link for more information. So far what I have, with equivalent English in parenthesis, is:

Presentador (Presented By):
Ubicación (Location):
Fecha (Date):
Informaciones (More Information) [link]

Is 'presentador' correct, or what word would a native Spanish speaker use to list the presenter?

Comment: Presentador is correct but you should say **Información** or **Más información** instead of _Informaciones_.

Comment: Ponente is also often used instead of presentador/a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer ***Ponente*** rather than *Presentador*, but both are correct.

Instead of "Informaciones" you should use **Más información: [link]**