# Informaciones vs. información - when to use which?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, sustantivos, hispanoamérica

In another question I asked, [How to say 'presenter' in a workshop?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19181/how-to-say-presenter-in-a-workshop) I used "informaciones" to link to 'more information'. At first I used "mas información" but a fluent (not native, however) Spanish speaker said "informaciones" was used in that context (a workshop description) to link to more information.

That leads me to ask:
What is the difference between 'informaciones' and 'información', and what is the appropriate context/usage for each?

This is mainly for use in Mexico but also for broader Latin American audiences.

Comment: I haven't heard "_informaciones_" in my life, we don't use it, at least in Spain. @cr0 if you are going to keep asking about the workshop, it'd be better to specify the country. Can change a lot between different countries.

Comment: Right @Nox, in the last question I specified hispanoamerica and the same applies here. I'll update that. More specifically, this is for Mexico but with broad Latin American audiences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Información* is more common, but somebody could use *informaciones* to highlight that there are several sources of information or information of different kinds or even contradictory information.

Anyway the examples provided by Rodrigo are considered (such as oficina de informaciones) wrong in Spain.

Answer (score 8):

As [I told you on that other answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19181/how-to-say-presenter-in-a-workshop#comment28636_19181) *Informaciones* sounds wrong. I've heard it a lot from Brazilians that learned Spanish so I guess in Portuguese it is fine.

If you look at most definitions on RAE you will see that **Información** being singular refers to plural "knowledge or data"

Check definitions 4, 5 and 6:

> 1. f. Acción y efecto de informar.
> 2. f. Oficina donde se informa sobre algo.
> 3. f. Averiguación jurídica y legal de un hecho o delito.
> 4. f. Pruebas que se hacen de la calidad y circunstancias necesarias en una persona para un empleo u honor. U. m. en pl.
> 5. f. Comunicación o adquisición de conocimientos que permiten ampliar o precisar los que se poseen sobre una materia determinada.
> 6. f. Conocimientos comunicados o adquiridos mediante una información.
> 7. f. Biol. Propiedad intrínseca de ciertos biopolímeros, como los ácidos nucleicos, originada por la secuencia de las unidades
>      componentes.
> 8. f. desus. Educación, instrucción.

In definitions 5, 6 when it means "knowledge or data" notice that it is defined as "conocimiento**s**" in plural.

So in this case it is the same as in English where you do not say <strike>**more informations**</strike>  since the use of the singular form implies that following the link you will find several pieces of information/data.

Answer (score 7):

En México el término "informaciones" no suena natural. De hecho, no recuerdo haberlo visto u oído en ninguna publicación. Yo descartaría su uso.

Definitivamente, **más información** es la fórmula más general que puedes utilizar. Es simple y ampliamente usada; además es, en mi opinión, el equivalente más cercano al texto en inglés **more information**. Otra fórmula general es: **información relevante**.

Dependiendo de la información que esté ligada al hipertexto, sin embargo, puedes recurrir a textos alternativos cómo:

- Ligas de interés (links)
- Lectura alternativa (alternative reading)
- Acerca del autor (about the author)
- Fuentes de información (information sources)
- Publicaciones relevantes (media)

Como puedes ver, los textos de la lista son de carácter más específico y su uso se restringe a la naturaleza de la información que se liga.

Comment: Excepto lo de ligas de interés, que yo sepa todo lo dicho es correcto también para España.

Comment: I agree with @Nox. We usually see **Vínculos de interés** instead of ligas.

Answer (score 1):

In **Chile** they are synonymous and I would say that we definitely prefer the plural:

> Oficina de informaciones (information office)
>
> Solicite más informaciones al fono xxxxx (request more information on phone xxxxxx)

Comment: aprendí algo nuevo fono=[1. m. Arg., Bol., Chile, Ec. y Perú. auricular (‖ parte del teléfono que se aplica al oído).](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ICM0Eov)

Answer (score 1):

La RAE utiliza en su propia página, el término "informaciones" en más de una oportunidad. Por lo que se puede afirmar que su uso pertenece a la variedad estándar de la lengua castellana. Sin embargo, para casi cualquier uso coloquial, es preferible "información" ya que "informaciones" suena poco común para la mayoría de la audiencia latinoamericana, al menos.

El vocablo acepta tanto la versión singular, como la plural. Pero el singular es preferible casi siempre, y son muy restringidos los contextos en donde un plural resultaría necesario (si bien, en mi opinión, el singular también se podría usar en estos pocos casos).