# ¿Existe la palabra informaciones (el plural de información)?

Tags: plurales

Esa es mi pregunta, y en ese caso estamos hablando de sustantivo contable? Por ejemplo, ¿se puede decir "Algunos centros de comercio han incluido más de 100 informaciones."
y
"Y unas cuantas informaciones que se han estado diciendo por ahí. "?

Comment: Tu respuesta puede encontrarse aquí: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19186/informaciones-vs-informaci%C3%B3n-when-to-use-which

Comment: Mi opinión es que el sustantivo "información" puede utilizarse en plural cuando "informaciones" se refiere a datos provenientes de distintas fuentes o suministrados en distintos momentos. Entonces, cada una de la informaciones se referirá a cada uno de los datos o grupos de datos proporcionados en esas distintas instancias.